# How to create a timer in javascript that limits an action

Tags: javascript

I would like to limit the use of the space bar in an application to once every second but I don't know how to implement it, this is my function

```
      document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
        if (event.code === 'Space') {
          console.log('Space pressed')
          this.y-=1;
        }
      })
```

Comment: get the time, compare it with the previous time with an if statement around your logic, then store the time for the next run.

Comment: This should be easy with rxjs, observable from action and throttling operator.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is probably the easiest solution without additional [Timing Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Every time your `keyup` event is fired you check if your delay time (e. g. 2 seconds -> 2000 ms) have passed. If that is the case you can go on and set `now` to the new latest value the space-bar has been clicked.

```js
const delay = 2000;
let now = Date.now();

document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (Date.now() > now + delay) {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
      console.log('Space pressed')
      this.y -= 1;
    }
    now = Date.now();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to do that would be,

```
let disable = false;

document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {

    // If disabled then do nothing
    if( disable ){
        return; 
    }
    
    // Set disable to true to prevent future actions
    disable = true; 

    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        console.log('Space pressed')
        this.y-=1;
    }

    // Turn off disable after 1 second 
    setTimeout( function(){ disable = false; },1000); 

})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setInterval()`

```js
function limiter() {
  document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
      console.log('Space pressed')
      this.y -= 1;
    }
  }, {
    once: true
  })
}

setInterval(limiter, 1000);
```

Comment: Keeps adding listeners and doesn't guarantee one second separation

Comment: I used this `{once: true}`. And how come it does not guarantee one second separation?

Comment: `{once: true}` is per event listener but there are many being added. As for the one second I can press space 100ms before end of interval and 105ms later. Test this yourself by letting it run for a few seconds then hit space

Comment: I can do something about the event listener being added only once, but I don't know about making the setInterval more accurate. For that to work it would require knowing how much the delay is, and that would be another function would it not? Or are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Using a setTimeout inside one listener is how I would approach it